# How to loop a result-set and Save it in list of maps

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to loop a Result set and store the values in Map and save the map into list but when i execute, for the first loop i'am getting the data correctly but for the second time i'am receiving twice the value and if the loop run for nth time the result i am getting n times.

Below is the code!

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> value = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
PreparedStatement selectStmt;
selectStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from ETR_INT_partc_DOCM  where DOCM_TYP_CDE ='22'");
ResultSet result = selectStmt.executeQuery();
while (result.next()) {
    HashMap<String, String> resultValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    resultValues.put("PARTC_ID", result.getString("PARTC_ID"));
    resultValues.put("FILE_NME", result.getString("FILE_NME"));
    resultValues.put("LOC_ID", result.getString("LOC_ID"));
    resultValues.put("CRTE_DTE", result.getString("CRTE_DTE"));
    resultValues.put("CRTE_BY", result.getString("CRTE_BY"));
    value.add(resultValues);
    System.out.println(value);
    resultValues.clear();
}
genarateXML(value, sheet)
```

Comment: why are you calling the: resultValues.clear()??  you just added that HashMap to values but then clear it, then you create a new instance?  makes no sense to me.  That line seems wrong to me.

Comment: The list `values` seems to be a class member and you don't empty/clear it before each call.

Comment: What do you expect print `value` to print out?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicate rows in the table? What are you getting on sysout?

Comment: Also there's really no need to clear, as you are creating a new map each iteration.

Comment: Thank you Peeskillet, i removed it

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codesuggestions.com/java/apache-commons-dbutils-tutorial/, specifically MapListHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ResultSet result = selectStmt.executeQuery();
HashMap<String, String> resultValues;
while (result.next()) {
    resultValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    resultValues.put("PARTC_ID", result.getString("PARTC_ID"));
    resultValues.put("FILE_NME", result.getString("FILE_NME"));
    resultValues.put("LOC_ID", result.getString("LOC_ID"));
    resultValues.put("CRTE_DTE", result.getString("CRTE_DTE"));
    resultValues.put("CRTE_BY", result.getString("CRTE_BY"));
    value.add(resultValues);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Not sure this would work, as OP want a list of maps i believe

Comment: I tried the As Paul sugested but the result is still the same i am getting values repeatedly for example for first loop it is printing as File_name,Something and second time ties printing [{File_name2,Somthing_2}], [{File_name2,Somthing_2}]

Comment: You mean for the second time, it prints "[{File_name2,Somthing_2}], [{File_name2,Somthing_2}]" rather than "[{File_name2,Somthing_2}]"? Interesting...